# HTMLElement.offsetTop works with static parent element

Tags: html

https://jsfiddle.net/6vqbLm5c/29/

HTML:

```
<div>
    <p id="par">paragraph</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
p {
  margin:0;
}

div {
  padding: 10px;
}

body {
  margin:0;
}
```

p.offsetTop returns 10px. My understanding is that the parent element div has position static set by default and according to the [offsetTop documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetTop) offsetTop is the number of pixels from the top of the closest relatively positioned parent element. So why is it still returning 10px even though p does not have a parent element that is relatively positioned?

Comment: The documentation is not clear, but the offsetTop attribute refers to the position of all parent relative elements in case [https://jsfiddle.net/ujsmhqx0/7/](https://jsfiddle.net/ujsmhqx0/7/) for example, the result is 20 because the "p" element is relative only to red box. Remove `position: absolute` code and the result is 30, because all elemets are relative

Comment: You can check HTMLElement.offsetParent to determine which ancestor it will be relative to. In your case, it's the `<body>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distinction appears to lie in **[the description for `position: relative`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#relative)**:

> The element is positioned according to the normal flow of the document, and then offset *relative to itself* based on the values of `top`, `right`, `bottom`, and `left`. The offset does not affect the position of any other elements; thus, the space given for the element in the page layout is the same as if position were `static`.

And **[the documentation for the visual formatting model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Visual_formatting_model#Normal_flow)**:

> The normal flow is triggered when the CSS position is set to the value `static` or `relative`, and if the CSS `float` is set to the value `none`.
>   
> ...
>     In `static` positioning, triggered by the value `static` of the `position` property, the boxes are drawn at the exact position defined by the normal flow layout.

That is to say, that when **no** positioned elements exist on the page, all elements fall within the "normal flow", with each element's positioning determined by each of its ancestors.

This becomes apparent when you apply `margin` to `<body>`; the `offsetTop` increases to accommodate the margin:

```js
var p = document.getElementById('par');
console.log(p.offsetTop)
```

```css
p {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  padding: 20px;
}

body {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p id="par">paragraph</p>
</div>
```

And can be further enhanced when modifying `<html>` itself:

```js
var p = document.getElementById('par');
console.log(p.offsetTop)
```

```css
p {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  padding: 20px;
}

body {
  margin: 10px;
}

html {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p id="par">paragraph</p>
</div>
```

And thus, the `offsetTop` increases to accommodate the ancestors as well, regardless of the fact that there is no positioned ancestor.